# Repetitive algebra and indecomposable projectives

Tags: abstract-algebra, representation-theory, representation-of-algebras

Let $A$ be a finite dimensional basic algebra over an algebraically closed field $k$. We denote by $D$ the standart duality $D(A) = \text{Hom}_k(A,k)$. The repetitive algebra $\hat{A}$ of $A$ is a Frobenius algebra with underlying vector space
$$\hat{A} = \left(\bigoplus_{i\in\mathbb{Z}}A\right)\oplus\left(\bigoplus_{i\in\mathbb{Z}}D(A)\right)$$

and multiplication

$$(a_i,\phi_i)_{i\in\mathbb{Z}}(b_i, \psi_i)_{i\in\mathbb{Z}} = (a_ib_i, a_{i+1}\psi_i + b_i\phi_i)_{i\in\mathbb{Z}}.$$

A finite dimensional $\hat{A}$-module can be viewed as a sequence of $A$-modules $(M_i,f_i)_{i\in\mathbb{Z}}$ with almost all being zero, together with maps

$$f_i : D(A)\otimes M_i \longrightarrow M_{i+1}$$

such that $f_{i+1}(1\otimes f_i) = 0$.

Let $\delta_{pi}$ be Kroneker delta. Corresponding to the decomposition of the local unit $1_p = (\delta_{ip},0)_{i\in\mathbb{Z}}$ in primitive, pairwise orthogonal idempotens, $e_{pj} = (\delta_{ip}e_j,0)_{i\in\mathbb{Z}}$ we get left ideals

$$\hat{A}e_{pj} = \begin{pmatrix}\dots\\0\\Ae_j\oplus D(A)e_j\\0\\ \dots\end{pmatrix},$$
where the non-zero entry is on the $p$-th position. And here is where my problem lies: This module  $\hat{A}e_{pj}$ should be indecomposable, but I don't understand why
$$\begin{pmatrix}\dots\\0\\Ae_j\\0\\ \dots\end{pmatrix}$$ is not a direct summand. And by that I mean that we find a split mono

$$\iota: \begin{pmatrix}\dots\\0\\Ae_j\\0\\ \dots\end{pmatrix} \longrightarrow \begin{pmatrix}\dots\\0\\Ae_j\oplus D(A)e_j\\0\\ \dots\end{pmatrix}$$

given by locally split monos that are compatible with the morphisms $f_i$ from the definition.

I've been using the book *Triangulated Categories in the Representation Theory of Finite Dimensional Algebras* by Dieter Happel, so any further literature suggestions or explenation as to why $\hat{A}e_{pj}$ is indecomposable would be extremely appreciated!

I'm trying to understand the simple $\hat{A}$-modules so any literature suggestions regarding this will also be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Locally we have the algebra
$$ \begin{pmatrix}A&0\\D(A)&A\end{pmatrix} $$
and your module is
$$ \begin{pmatrix}Ae_j\\D(A)e_j\end{pmatrix}. $$
In other words we have $M_p=Ae_j$, $M_{p+1}=D(A)e_j$, and $f_p$ is just the natural multiplication map $D(A)\otimes Ae_j\xrightarrow{\sim}D(A)e_j$.

Now there is a natural epimorphism to the module
$$ \begin{pmatrix}Ae_j\\0\end{pmatrix} $$
which has $M_p=Ae_j$ and $M_{p+1}=0$, but there is no non-zero module homomorphism in the other direction, since this require morphisms yielding the vertical maps in the commutative square
$$ \require{AMScd}\begin{CD}
D(A)\otimes Ae_j @>>> 0\\
@VVV @VVV\\
D(A)\otimes Ae_j @>{\sim}>> D(A)e_j
\end{CD} $$

As for the finite dimensional simple modules for the repetitive algebra, there will be a maximal index $p$ such that $M_p\neq0$. Then every $A$-submodule of $M_p$ will give a submodule of the module for the repetitive algebra, so will be everything. Thus the simple modules for $\hat A$ are the simple $A$-modules supported in a single degree.

Comment: Thank you so much! This was very helpful:)